# resque worker error when forking [Ruby, Redis]

Tags: ruby, redis, rake, resque

I'm having a difficulty with processing resque tasks which were enqueued.
The whole enqueuing part goes well - I can see it in Redis and also Resque.info shows the pending tasks number incrementing as it should.

If I run the perform method of the Job class explicitly - everything works fine.

Once the worker come alive - all the tasks fail.

This is the Job class:

```
class TestJob
  @queue = :test1_queue

  def self.perform(str)
    begin
      f = open('/tmp/test.txt', 'a')
      f.write("#{Time.now.to_s} #{str} in self.perform\n")
    rescue Exception => e
      f.write("#{Time.now.to_s} #{str} in self.perform\n#{e.message}\n#{e.backtrace}\n")
    ensure
      f.close
    end
  end  
end
```

The resque.rb initializer:

```
require 'resque'
require 'redis'
Dir['../../jobs'].each { |file| require file }

Resque.redis = $resque_redis
Resque.logger.level = Logger::WARN
Resque.after_fork do |_|
  $resque_redis.client.reconnect
end
```

Redis initializer:

```
require 'redis'
$resque_redis = Redis.new(:host => REDIS_BITMAP_HOST,  :port => REDIS_PORT, :db => 0, :timeout => 30)
```

config file to start the worker with god:

```
require_relative './common.rb'
watch_resque_process('test1', 1)
```

God definitions:

```
$home_dir = ENV["HOME"]
$rack_env = ENV["ETL_ENV"] || "development"

def create_deafult_monitoring_scheme(watch)
  # Restart if memory is above 150 Megabytes or CPU is above 50% for 5 consecutive intervals
  watch.restart_if do |restart|
    restart.condition(:memory_usage) do |c|
      c.above = 150.megabytes
      c.times = [3, 5] # 3 out of 5 intervals
    end

    restart.condition(:cpu_usage) do |c|
      c.above = 50.percent
      c.times = 5
    end
  end

  # The :flapping condition guards against the edge case wherein god rapidly starts or restarts your application.
  # If this watch is started or restarted five times withing 5 minutes, then unmonitor it for 10 minutes.
  # After 10 minutes, monitor it again to see if it was just a temporary problem; if the process is seen to be flapping five times within two hours, then give up completely.
  watch.lifecycle do |on|
    on.condition(:flapping) do |c|
      c.to_state      = [:start, :restart]
      c.times         = 5
      c.within        = 5.minute
      c.transition    = :unmonitored
      c.retry_in      = 10.minute
      c.retry_times   = 5
      c.retry_within  = 30.minute
    end
  end
end

def watch_resque_process(resque_process_name, worker_count=8)
  God.watch do |w|
    w.name      = "resque_work-#{resque_process_name}"
    w.start     = "cd #{$home_dir}/rtb-etl && COUNT=#{worker_count} QUEUE='#{resque_process_name}_queue' RACK_ENV=#{$rack_env} rake resque:workers"
    w.interval  = 30.seconds
    w.log       = File.join($home_dir, 'logs', 'resque', "resque_#{resque_process_name}.log")
    w.err_log   = File.join($home_dir, 'logs', 'resque', "resque_#{resque_process_name}.log")
    w.env       = { 'PIDFILE' => "#{$home_dir}/pids/#{w.name}.pid" }

    # Check if the process is still up every 5 seconds
    w.start_if do |start|
      start.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.interval = 5.seconds
        c.running = false
      end
    end

    create_deafult_monitoring_scheme(w)

  end
end

def watch_rake_task(rake_task_name, interval=30.seconds)
  God.watch do |w|
    w.name  = "rake_#{rake_task_name}"
    # w.start = "cd #{$home_dir}/rtb-etl && RACK_ENV=#{$rack_env} bundle exec rake #{rake_task_name}"
    w.start = "cd #{$home_dir}/rtb-etl && RACK_ENV=#{$rack_env} rake #{rake_task_name}"
    w.interval = interval
    w.log      = File.join($home_dir, 'logs', 'resque', "rake_#{rake_task_name}.log")
    w.err_log  = File.join($home_dir, 'logs', 'resque', "rake_#{rake_task_name}.log")
    w.env      = { 'PIDFILE' => "#{$home_dir}/pids/#{w.name}.pid" }

    # Check if the process is still up every 30 seconds
    w.start_if do |start|
      start.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.interval = interval
        c.running = false
      end
    end

    create_deafult_monitoring_scheme(w)

  end
end
```

when I run the follwoing:
    irb(main):004:0> Resque.enqueue(TestJob, 'foo')
    => true

In order to check what went wrong, I run in irb the following:

```
Resque::Failure.all(0,20).each { |job|
   puts "#{job["exception"]}  #{job["backtrace"]}"
}
```

and get this result:

```
[{"failed_at"=>"2015/08/26 17:35:00 UTC", 
"payload"=>{"class"=>"TestJob", "args"=>["foo"]},     
"exception"=>"NoMethodError", 
"error"=>"undefined method `client' for nil:NilClass", 
"backtrace"=>[], "worker"=>"ip-172-31-11-211:5006:test1_queue",
"queue"=>"test1_queue"}]
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure that your Redis initializer is loaded before your resque.rb? Seems like the `$resque_redis` global is `nil`

Comment: Yes, made sure it is loaded before:

    irb(main):010:0> Resque.redis
    => #<Redis::Namespace:0x00000001cb4098 @namespace=:resque, @redis=#<Redis client v3.2.1 for redis://localhost:6379/0>, @warning=true, @deprecations=false>

Comment: That is your Redis class, did what is the output if you load up your DRB and call `$resque_redis`, the global var?

Comment: @yez you are right, $resque_redis yields nil.
I don't understand why this global var does not hold the value it had assigned to :\

Comment: I would check to make sure your redis initializer file is loaded before you use it.

Comment: Thanks @yez, but even though it is loaded, I still can't make it work nor think of where could the problem be :\

Comment: If you host the full files in question somewhere (or have a public github) I can take a closer look.